# WPf - Place an horizontal scroll bar if the image is lengthier than the image box width

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have an image control in WPF window. Width of images assigned in that image box may be lengthier than the image box width. I want to place an horizontal scroll bar inside the image box in such a condition. Please help if you know the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="C:\Image.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Here is my code:

<ScrollViewer Height="106" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,0,3,58" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Image Margin="0,3,0,58" Name="queimag" Stretch="None" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="805" Height="106" />
        </ScrollViewer>

Comment: Could you edit your original question and but that in there? Your original question has no context to it.

Comment: The `Source` attribute on the `Image` tag is not set ... where are you doing that?

Comment: OK, I think I see it too ... I removed the `Margin` attribute altogether from your `Image` tag, and it pretty much cleared up ... you're effectively clipping your image inside the `ScrollViewer`.

Also, I'm pretty sure by the time you're done, you're going to want `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`, too.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for the reply @John. I set the  imagesource programmatically

Comment: I need only horizontal tool bar. that is why i did'nt give VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

Comment: If setting your `Margin="0,0,0,0"` (or removing the attribute altogether) solved your problem, please mark as answer

Comment: RE not using `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`: OK, but you probably want to set your `MinHeight` based on the characteristics of the images you're processing, and make sure somehow that the images themselves respect this value, or you're going to wind up clipping taller ones at the bottom.

Comment: actually I have set up the height properties already and it's done. I want to process with the width of the image. (Horizontal scroll bar)